# sequential load function jSon API in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sequential

i have a problem, went i load two function to hit API, application loading very slow sometimes resulted out of the application.

this is my code:

```
[self loadJSonNews];
[self loadJSonPopular];
```

how to make this function sequential.

thanks,

Comment: And what does your code? What's behind these methods?

Comment: both of them methode is call API to get jSon data with NSURL

Comment: Synchronous? Asynchronous?

Comment: @larme both of them using Synchronous, ---[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];----